# How to create a reponsive image and button on the right?

Tags: html, css

I want to create template contains :

- On the left : Have a image
- On the right: Have 4 buttons

My examlple : 
[image]

What can I do to create that design with HTMl & CSS ?
Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `display:flex;` and `display:grid;` to do this. This is a sample code. Hope it helps

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="button">
      Button 1
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 2
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 3
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: I have added media queries and shortened the css code in this snippet so that the button will be shown below the image in smaller screens**

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .image {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="button">
      Button 1
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 2
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 3
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much
It worked well
How can I increase the width of the buttons?
I have tried changing the {padding: 10px 15px;} but no success

Comment: I've tried to change the grid-template-column to: 200px 200px; the buttons width is ok now but when I try to view on the mobile the image disappear
is there a way to stack the buttons under the image when I am on the mobile?

Comment: You can do this by adding media queries. Check the second snippet I added. Hope it solves your problem

Comment: It works perfect!!!
Can I write the CSS inline style as well?
Because I need it for a Wordpress page.

Comment: Sorry for be such a pain in the ass but how can I change the size of the img?
thank you

Comment: You can simply use the width and height attribute in the img tag. Something like this: <img src="example.png" width="200" height="100">

Comment: Thank you !!!
When I resize the screen Is there a way to make stack the 4 buttons vertically instead than horizontally?

Comment: Yes in the media queries just add the .button-container class and give the grid-template-columns attribute as 100px (just one value instead of two). Eg:- @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
.button-container {
     grid-template-columns: 100px; }
}

Comment: Thank you very much
You really helped me a lot and I also learned some new stuffs as well
Flexbox is great!!!!

Comment: Try https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox or https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/i-just-launched-a-free-full-length-flexbox-course-where-you-can-build-projects-interactively-1860e3d3c4af/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 *{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; }
  .img_box_btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .img_box_btn .left {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 40%;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .img_box_btn img {
  max-width: 100%;
  }
  .img_box_btn  .right {
  padding: 0 15px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 60%;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
  }
  ul.list-btn-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  list-style: none;
  }
  ul.list-btn-box li {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  }
  .img_box_btn * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ul.list-btn-box li .btn-cus {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .img_box_btn .left,.img_box_btn .right {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>responsive image and four buttons</title>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="max-width: 800px; margin: 15px auto; padding: 0  15px;">
   <div class="img_box_btn">
    <div class="left">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <ul class="list-btn-box">
      <li><button class="btn-cus">button 01</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-cus">button 02</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-cus">button 03</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-cus">button 04</button></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that can be done. However, I've used bootstrap to make things simple. Please review the following code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Sample Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 img-col">
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/iqoncept/iqoncept1406/iqoncept140600148/29496890-case-study-words-in-a-circle-or-round-stamp-with-red-ink-to-symbolize-a-business-example-or-anecdote.jpg" alt="sample" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 btn-col">
                <div class="row row-1">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button>
                            BTN-1
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button>
                            BTN-2
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button>
                            BTN-3
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button>
                            BTN-4
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS for the same:

```
.img-col, .btn-col {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.row .img-col {
    text-align: center;
}

.img-col .image {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-col {
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.btn-col .row-1{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

This will make it look like this: [image: Screenshot of the result of above code]